# BootStrap have mobile navbar entire bar dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

My site is gitlit.org and when I go mobile or scale my browser the navbar switches to the mobiel design without issues and I can click the three white lines (menu) button and it works but clicking Home does nothing. Is there a way so that the entire bar is clickable?

My navbar code:

```
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">resources</a></li>
      <li><a href="sermons.php">sermons</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">ministries</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my custom CSS that is applied to the NavBar, I did not edit the main bootstrap css:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #000;
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    border: 0px solid #000;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
}
.navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    color: #fdbb20;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #fdbb20;
}
.navbar-brand {
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #fdbb20;
}
```

Comment: posting just a link to a site is not a good idea... the question can attract few downvotes and could get closed

Comment: Thanks for this, im new here. I have added in the html/css code.

Comment: did you fix it... it seems to be working now

Comment: No, if I tap on Home it does not expand the list. Does it work for you?

Comment: Are you on bootstrap 2 or 3?

Comment: I am currently on 3 RC1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly... why is home outside your `.navbar-nav` div?

Shouldn't you move it inside with the rest of the menu?

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="sermons.php">sermons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">ministries</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you want it to behave as the 3 little lines then you should add a `class` and two `data-` attributes like so:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">Home</a>
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="sermons.php">sermons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">ministries</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is what you meant and if it worked for you, if it's the right answer for this question remember to mark it... if not just let me know so I can modify it to be the right answer :)

Comment: Hey, the first part wont work because I am wanting a word to display on the nav, I do not plan on keeping it 'Home'. Your second code was close but it just replaces the three span "icon-bar" (white lines) with the word 'Home'.

Comment: Could you be very specific of what you want to achieve? To me it's not that it replaced the `icon-bar` span, it's that I simply didn't add it to my code. If you explain exactly what your end product is supposed to look like then I can definitively help.

Comment: Ok, what I am wanting to make the 'Home' button trigger the dropdown because currently the only way to have the navbar dropdown is by clicking the span. The rest of the bar does nothing.

Comment: Ok, let me know if this fiddle works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/KVzKt/ if it does (it's a full span button to click with a fire icon) then I will update it on my answer.

Comment: I think this code is broken, it's not being used properly by bootstrap so you will need to extend it with an @media query to make sure your home button hides when the screen is big enough for your menu to display. So this was a "hackish" solution based on your markup. The reason it's not disappearing the home button is because the classes and elements are not nested according to the bootstrap documentation

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I noticed that also and have included @media (min-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-brand {
  display: none;
 }
} 
In my main css file :)